# Will a workflow trigger another workflow if it changes value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have LIST A and LIST B. If a workflow in LIST A runs and changes a value in LIST B will the workflow on LIST B be triggered? The LIST B workflow is set to run on a change event run? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this works for the 2010 workflow platform. If you do have the 2013 workflow platform configured up, there is a action that let's you trigger one or several other workflows based on your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,List B workflow would run in your scenario